# How to remove or edit WordPress breadcrumb?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, breadcrumbs

The previous developer added breadcrumb. I do not know how to add.

There are places I need to edit the plugin if I can't edit it I need to remove it somehow. We use WordPress. I'm not a developer. I have intermediate knowledge of the subject.

[link](https://www.tekniknokta.com.tr/kendin-yap-diy-veri-kurtarma-yontemlerine-guvenebilir-miyiz/)

Comment: Could you provide us with some more info? What plugin are you using? Do you have some sample code? This is a developer forum, so we can only help you with programming questions.

Comment: Can you add the page link with breadcrumb?

Comment: Can you send some code like how you have managed the breadcrumb in your site? So, we can check if it comes from plugin or custom code.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the link and I'm not seeing any plugin for the breadcrumbs. Not sure where the style is being implemented because all styles have been minified by your cache plugin.

A fast solution could be to go to the site customizer and add some custom css:

```
#breadcrumbss {display: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem. I found it in "single.php". For this, I had to download a site backup and do a keyword search, but I did.

Answer (score 0):

I entered the theme folder under the wp-content file. I found them in the "single.php" file found there. edited. /public_html/wp-content/themes/qwerty/single.php